# DOMXpath query returns null

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("https://www.tipico.com/en/wettschein/bslc-bVysdHEpshHRDMQ7E-Y5Q%3D%3D/");

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$footer = $xpath->query("//div[@class='t_foot']/div[1]/div[1]");
var_dump($footer->item(0)->nodeValue);
```

Shouldn't this return `48,37`? I have other xpath queries which are working, but especially this is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `t_foot` is not the only class on the element you are trying to get, so the class name is not equal to the string `t_foot`. Instead you should select element which class *contains* `t_foot`. So XPath expression should be this:

```
$footer = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "t_foot")]/div[1]/div[1]');
```

Comment: Ah, I thought about this earlier. Thank you, it works!